# error: waitpid for fetch-pack failed: No child processes -- any permanent solution

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio-code

I am getting this error when running git pull.

```
error: waitpid for fetch-pack failed: No child processes
```

If I run the git using admin, then it runs fine. But does anyone have any permanent solution for this? I have installed the latest version of git on windows also.

I am not able to use git properly on VScode also.